# Why some Wi-Fis do not work (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, connection, madwifi

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows on my HP 255 G7 some months ago and always had troubles with WiFis. With university's WiFi everything is fine, when I'm home the connection is very weak and now that I came back to my parents house for the holidays the connection keeps falling down and I cannot even use it. On other laptops and on my phone all these WiFis work fine. Please help me out, this is getting really annoying.

Comment: Check the router settings before anything else. Likely you'll find it's an old router still using WEP and/or TKIP

Comment: Weirdly, under 'details' it says WPA2, while under 'security' I have WPA & WPA2 personal

Comment: Again, check the **router**, not Ubuntu's system settings.

Comment: I now used the command $> nmcli device wifi list and it's again WPA2. But tell me if this is again wrong (beginner here)

Comment: I'll tell you the recommended **router** settings: WPA2-AES only, no WPA/WPA2 mixed mode, no WEP obviously and no TKIP encryption either. Modern routers should be like this by default but it's worth checking. Again, I'm talking about the **router**, not Ubuntu or any other OS.

Comment: Done. But no improvements. I can also tell you that if I use an ethernet cable I have no connection issues.